# Is it possible to use domain names in place of IP addresses for peer nodes (static nodes) or bootnotes in the configuration for starting a geth node?

Tags: go-ethereum, enode, dns

I've searched quite a bit not been able to find any examples using domain names or indeed any reason why it can't be used.

e.g. to start a node with bootnodes, the format is as below using ip addresses

```
geth --bootnodes enode://pubkey1@ip1:port1
```

I'm interested because for a private network I'm looking to build static IP addresses aren't really an option.

Is it possible to do:

```
geth --bootnodes enode://pubkey1@mydomain.com:port1
```

This would allow dynamic IPs for nodes.

Is this a security risk?

Many thanks

Comment: Might make yourself open to a denial of service attack if someone attacks DNS (either by making the DNS entry unavailable or changing the reported IP).

Comment: Not necessarily. The DNS name may be resolved by your trusted DNS servers on your internal network. I think this feature would really be helpful when deployed with modern orchestration frameworks (e.g. with Docker stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

referring to the official doc, no it is not possible to use DNS domain names in enode URL:

> The hostname can only be given as an IP address, DNS domain names are not allowed

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format

I don't know why it's not supported though

Comment: Thanks - I have never seen that wiki despite searching! Would love to know why though...

Answer (score 1):

There is an update to this and DNS names are being accepted to add peeers from geth version of 1.9.3.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.9.3